# Notification when a UIView is destroyed

Tags: ios5, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell (subclassed) and it works great. Part of the cell is a UITextField, which I expose externally as a @property. However, everything is managed internally within the cell, including allocating + setting up the UITextField in the initWithStyle function.

What I've noticed is when I create a decent sized table (more cells than can be displayed on the page at once) then select one of the UITextField's, type a little, finally scroll way down and select another cell, my program crashes.

My program does *not* crash when I:

- repeat the steps above minus typing in the original cell
- type in a UITextField, and then scroll and type in a close by text field.
- jump right into any specific text field and start typing

Right now, I'm currently not reusing cells, but will once all the bugs are out.

Looking through the crash stack, this seems to be happening because the program is trying to resign the firstresponder of the original text field. Has this text field been accidentally deallocated? I don't think so because I am able to select a cell, scroll way off screen, start typing, then scroll all the way back up and see the contents I just typed. Has the internal *textfield pointer been altered? It shouldn't have been as I only assign to it in the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: function of the overloaded UITableViewCell -- and even if it were, it isn't I who is resigning; I don't even call resignFirstResponder anywhere in my code.

So is there a way I can identify if my UIView (eg UITableViewCell) has scrolled off screen (from within the UITableViewCell--preferably by overloading some method)? viewDidUnload comes to mind, but that's for viewControllers. If I had such a method, I would utilize it to resignFirstResponder on the textfield and any other processing I wanted to handle on that.

Some code:

```
// In the .h
@interface mycell:UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textfield;
@end

// In the .m
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuse];
    if (!self) return self;

    self.textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.textfield setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:self.textfield];
    return self;
}
```

Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: What `UITextField` delegate methods are you implementing? And what do their implementations look like?

Comment: Why aren't you reusing the tableview cells?